# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'NeverBounce\API\NB_Auth' not found in C:\Users\Thibault\Downloads\neverbounce-client-master\never.php:15

Tags: php, api, authentication

I try to use NeverBounce API-PHP. But when i want to launch my Php file i had this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'NeverBounce\API\NB_Auth' not found
>   in C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\neverbounce-client-master\never.php:15
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\neverbounce-client-master\never.php on
>   line 15

Line 15 : `NB_Auth::auth($apisecret, $apikey)`;

The file that contains all the API classes is in the file, where is my class never.php.

Comment: Did you include file with NB_Auth class? Or is there an autoloader in your project?  Composer autoload for example  `require (__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: There an autoloader in my project

Comment: One more guess: there is a problem with namespaces. Can you please show whole never.php.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6ygfbNKq

Comment: I've tried your code and I don't receive such error.  
Please check is there mention about `NeverBounce\API` in composer/autoload_static.php or composer/autoload_psr4.php? 
If no try `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added the listed options as an answer. Please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following items:

1. Check if the file with your class was included (`equire() or include()`), especially if there is no autoloader in your project?
2. Check if there are no problems with namespaces in you class?
3. If you use composer autoloader – try to run  `composer dump-autoload` to update your autoloader